# I Have a Problem while installing laravel on windows 10

Tags: composer-php, laravel-8, http-proxy, malformed

In my Pc Composer is Install But when I type the command
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
It Give me the error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBoK1.png)

And I run the command composer create-project laravel/laravel {directory} 4.2 --prefer-dist
It give me the same error
Please Help Me
Thanks In advance

Comment: Try `composer global require laravel/installer`

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)